# Dynamic memory allocation and sizeof()

Tags: c, sizeof, dynamic-memory-allocation

For allocating memory to two dimensional array dynamically, I write something like this

```
int **ar = (int **)malloc(row*sizeof(int*));
for(i = 0; i < row; i++) 
     ar[i] = (int*)malloc(col*sizeof(int));
```

I came across this code which does the same but i cannot understand the declaration.

```
double (*buf)[2] = (double (*)[2])malloc(count*sizeof(double [2]));// Explain this 


printf("%d, %d, %d, %d \n",sizeof(double));
printf(" %d",sizeof(buf[0]));
printf(" %d", sizeof(buf));
//prints 8, 16, 16, 4 when count is 3
```

The output of first `printf()` is trivial. Please help me with the next two.

Comment: http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=double+%28%2Abuf%29%5B2%5D

Comment: [Don't cast the result of `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/3425536).

Comment: @zenith I don't know why my prof taught me that way.

Answer (score 1):

```
double (*buf)[2] = (double (*)[2])malloc(count*sizeof(double [2]));// Explain this
```

This

```
double (*buf)[2]
```

defines `buf` to be a pointer to an array of 2 `double`s.

This

```
(double (*)[2])malloc(count*sizeof(double [2]));
```

can (and shall) be rewritten as

```
malloc(count * sizeof(double [2]));
```

The above line allocates memory with the size of `count` times "size for an array of 2 `double`s".

This

```
=
```

assigns the latter to the former.

It all ends up with `buf` pointing to an array of `count * 2` `double`s.

Access its elements like this

```
(*buf)[0][0];
```

Note that this approach creates a pointer to a "*linear*" array, that is an array where all elements are store in one continues block of memory.

Whereas the approch you 1st mention in you question creates a "*scattered*" array that is an array where each row might be located in a seperate block of memory.

---

This

```
printf("%d, %d, %d, %d \n",sizeof(double));
```

provokes undefined behaviour, as from its 1st (format) parameter the `printf` expects **four** addtional parameters and is being passed only **one**.

The size of a `double` typically is 8.

This

```
printf(" %d",sizeof(buf[0]));
```

prints the size of the first element that `buf` points to. As `buf` points to an array of 2 `double`s, it is expected to print 2 times "size of a `double`" which  2 * 8 = 16.

This

```
printf(" %d", sizeof(buf));
```

prints the size of `buf`. As `buf` is defined as a pointer, the size of a pointer on is printed. This typically is 4 for a 32bit implementation and 8 for 64bit implementation.

Note: The value of `count` does not appear in any of the sizes printed above, not directly, nor indireclty, as In C it is not possible to derive from a pointer how much memory had been allocated to it.